# Update multiple columns in first row with data from other table without join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm moving a few boolean columns from the 1st row of a generic `settings` table into the 1st row of a `website_settings` table across a few MYSQL databases. I've created the new columns in my new table with a default false value.

I have a working query to copy data from the old table:

```
UPDATE website_settings
SET
  dark_mode_enabled = (SELECT dark_mode_enabled FROM settings ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
  header_enabled = (SELECT header_enabled FROM settings ORDER BY id LIMIT 1),
  footer_enabled = (SELECT footer_enabled FROM settings ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 1;
```

However for my own knowledge, I'm curious if there is a more cleaner way to write this, perhaps without the repetitive select queries to the same table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `join`:

```
UPDATE website_settings ws CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT s.*
        FROM settings s
        ORDER id DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) s
    SET ws.dark_mode_enabled = s.dark_mode_enabled,
        ws.header_enabled = s.header_enabled,
        ws.footer_enabled = s.footer_enabled
    LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that does not use JOIN:

```
INSERT INTO website_settings (id, dark_mode_enabled, header_enabled, footer_enabled)
 SELECT id, dark_mode_enabled, header_enabled, footer_enabled
 FROM settings ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  dark_mode_enabled = VALUES(dark_mode_enabled),
  header_enabled = VALUES(header_enabled),
  footer_enabled = VALUES(footer_enabled);
```